# How to set header for restful api authentication using RESTclient Addon Firefox

Tags: php, rest, yii, restful-authentication

I have this code from Yii Example

```
private function _checkAuth()
{
    // Check if we have the USERNAME and PASSWORD HTTP headers set?
    if(!(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_USERNAME']) and isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_PASSWORD']))) {
        // Error: Unauthorized

        $this->_sendResponse(401);
    }
    $username = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_USERNAME'];
    $password = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_PASSWORD'];
    // Find the user
    $user=User::model()->find('LOWER(username)=?',array(strtolower($username)));
    $this->_sendResponse('200','$username');
    if($user===null) {
        // Error: Unauthorized
        $this->_sendResponse(401, 'Error: User Name is invalid');
    } 

    else if(!$user->validatePassword($password)) {
        // Error: Unauthorized
        $this->_sendResponse(401, 'Error: User Password is invalid');
    }
}
```

How to set header information for authentication.
How to set HTTP_X_USERNAME and  HTTP_X_PASSWORD in request;

for the name, value and body of RESTClient addon?
Thank for advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand your question (same as [this post in yii forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/18412-new-yii-rest-tutorial/page__view__findpost__p__151819)) relates to the RESTClient addon. To set your headers in the RESTClient addon: use the 'headers' functionality:

- List item
- menu 'Headers'
- 'Custom Header'
- 'Name' : X_PASSWORD
- 'Value' : emo

And the same with X_USERNAME.

HTH,

JM.

Answer (score 6):

Hi I have resolved this issue with following server side code, set the HTTP Request headers as you are already doing on client side.

```
private function _checkAuth()
    {
        // Check if we have the USERNAME and PASSWORD HTTP headers set?

        $headers = apache_request_headers();

        if(!(isset($headers['X_'.self::APPLICATION_ID.'_USERNAME']) and isset($headers['X_'.self::APPLICATION_ID.'_PASSWORD']))) {
            // Error: Unauthorized
            $this->_sendResponse(401);
        }

        $username = $headers['X_'.self::APPLICATION_ID.'_USERNAME'];
        $password = $headers['X_'.self::APPLICATION_ID.'_PASSWORD'];
}
```